# CiviCRM 5.69.x Smarty3 errors

Tags: smarty3

When updating to ESR 5.69.x, we are running into errors with Smarty3 when updating the smarty path in civicrm.settings.php:

define('CIVICRM_SMARTY3_AUTOLOAD_PATH',
'/var/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/autoload.php');

$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Get_Plugin_Filepath'"
"code" => null
"exception" => SmartyException {#8284
#message: "undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Get_Plugin_Filepath'"
...

We are still trying to diagnose why this is happening, but we have upgraded some clients with no issues, and other clients with varying degrees of issues (donations, registrations, contact creations, etc.). Has anyone else encountered this issue when upgrading to 5.69.x?

System:
Drupal 7.99
CiviCRM 5.69.5
PHP 8.1

Full backtrace:

$Fatal Error Details = array:3 [
"message" => "undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Get_Plugin_Filepath'"
"code" => null
"exception" => SmartyException {#8284
#message: "undefined extension class 'Smarty_Internal_Runtime_Get_Plugin_Filepath'"
#code: 0
#file: "/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_undefined.php"
#line: 62
trace: {
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_undefined.php:62 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_extension_handler.php:133 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_data.php:290 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/Smarty/plugins/modifier.date_format.php:11 {
include_once
›  */
› require_once $smarty->_get_plugin_filepath('shared', 'make_timestamp');
› /**
arguments: {
$name: "_get_plugin_filepath"
$args: array:2 [ …2]
}
}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_method_loadplugin.php:90 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php:1065 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:841 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_compile_private_modifier.php:94 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:768 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:1501 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:565 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:2880 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:3481 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templateparser.php:3573 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_smartytemplatecompiler.php:128 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:481 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php:402 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_resource_recompiled.php:52 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php:136 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php:105 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:216 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:232 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:116 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/c3/de/cf/c3decff7ccfa9fdba7d3be9cc10e1d06f1108c3b_0.string.{eval var=$smartySingleUseString|smarty:nodefaults}.php:30 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_resource_base.php:123 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_template_compiled.php:114 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_template.php:216 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:232 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/smarty3/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php:116 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/String.php:1040 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Token/TokenCompatSubscriber.php:108 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:251 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:73 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php:263 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Token/TokenProcessor.php:397 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Token/TokenRow.php:327 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/TokenSmarty.php:67 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php:374 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/MessageTemplate.php:422 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/BAO/Event.php:1254 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/Registration/Confirm.php:895 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php:625 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php:144 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php:43 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php:203 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php:103 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php:355 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:322 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:69 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php:36 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module:472 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/includes/menu.inc:527 { …}
/var/www/wwwadmin/data/www/example.com/index.php:21 { …}
}
}
]

Comment: Do you have backtrace?

Comment: I just updated my initial question with the full backtrace - thank you for taking a look @Pradeep Nayak

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have your **Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)** message template customised which is causing the smarty issue

Comment: Yes you probably have something like `|date_format:"%s"` in it. Note the date_format modifier is deprecated in php 8. Consider switching to `|crmDate`.